# libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, gdal

yesterday the code was running but when I run my code today, the following error occurs:

```
runfile('/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py', wdir='/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-e8fdc416f3c8>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py', wdir='/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram')

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py", line 17, in <module>
import ogr

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ogr.py", line 2, in <module>
from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)

ImportError: /home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/../../../libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: _ZN11xercesc_3_211InputSource11setEncodingEPKDs
```

I also tried to reinstall all and installed `gdal` and `libgdal` again but the error still occurs. I use a virtual environment in which I have:

```
gdal                      2.2.4                    py36_0    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.2.4                hc8d23f9_1    anaconda
```

Well, I know the two are from different sources but this worked until yesterday.

I use Python 3.6.3 with Anaconda in Ubuntu 16.04.

**Update**

As I found out, this Problem also occur when I use PyCharm instead of Anaconda, with the same error. In this case I use GDAL downloaded with the pip command and a pre installed libgdal.

This is the error message in this case:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py", line 18, in <module>
import ogr
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ogr.py", line 2, in <module>
from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: _ZN11xercesc_3_111InputSource11setEncodingEPKt
```

For PyCharm I used Python 3.5.2.

Does someone has an idea?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If it worked yesterday, try looking at `conda list --revisions -n gmt-python2` to see what changed since.

I don't think Anaconda itself comes with `gdal` from the conda-forge channel, and `libgdal` from the anaconda channel. So it must have happened at some point.

You could try forcing Conda to update using either one of the channels. With GDAL I definitely prefer the conda-forge build since it has (at least had in the past) better working activation scripts which also correctly set the GDAL_DATA environment variable when switching environments.

```
conda install conda-forge::gdal=2.2.4 --force --update-dependencies
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will check it tomorrow when I'm back in the office. But I always have the problem that I turn off the PC with Anaconda in a special configuration with packages and at the next day, I have to start again with reinstalling the packages.

Comment: I tried it but sadly it didn't work. I also tried PyCharm as I updated in my question but the error still appear.